# Get column name ( Meta Data ) Talend

Tags: java, mysql, json, talend

I'm trying to export data and meta data from Mysql Database to a JSON .

My JSON output need to have this structure :

```
{     "classifier":[  
  {  
     "name":"Frequency",
     "value":"75 kHz"
  },
  {  
     "name":"depth",
     "value":"100 m"
  }   ]}
```

Frequency for me represent a column Name and 75 Khz is the value of the column for a specific row.

I'm using Talend data integration to do this, and i can get the data, but i can't figure out how to get the meta data, do i have to enter it myself ? or there is a more easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot export metadata of json file from Mysql because Mysql provide a structured data, hence we have to create our json structure independently using an existing file or manually, the easiest way is to create a sample file like the one used in your question. See [Talend Help](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforDataIntegrationUserGuide54EN/7.11.2+Setting+up+JSON+metadata+for+an+output+file).